# How to select check box without selecting the whole row (see body)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Say, I have an html:

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

1. When user clicks on the whole row, it becomes highlighted (`selected` class added by an `onClick` event). I attach `onClick` event to elements with class `.row`.
2. When user clicks on checkbox (which is inside `.row`), this checkbox becomes selected. But row should not be highlighted.

Is it possible to exclude the area of the checkbox from the area of the `.row` for an `onClick` event?

---

UPDATE

Here is what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/saAGU/

I don't want class to be toggled when I click exactly on checkbox.

---

UPDATE 2

Here is the working solution with jQuery for future use: http://jsfiddle.net/saAGU/2/

Comment: I think we're gonna need a little more code than that.  Could you give some of the javascript you're using for the onclick event, some more of the html, and any css if you have it?  Maybe set up a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: give us the full code with `onclick` events

Comment: anyone else notice this is a Javascript question with no mention of jQuery, with jQuery answers?  Javascript != jQuery

Comment: The question was very simple, I don't see any reason for more code. This is a simple question about event propagation. Why do you guys need more code?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea is right, it's like every javascript question must be answered with jQuery code.

Comment: I have updated my question with some jsfiddle. Please, check it. As to jQuery, it doesn't matter for me. I need any possible approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The right way to do it is putting a onclick event on the checkbox, capture the event and stop its propagation.

Something like this:

```
function checkboxClick (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Please tell me if it worked

Answer (score 2):

add click event to every checkbox and stop its propogation .this should work -

`e.stopPropagation` in event handler for checkbox click

http://jsfiddle.net/saAGU/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the event, and look at the event.toElement, you can see if they clicked on the .row or something else.

http://jsfiddle.net/saAGU/1/

```
$('.row').click(function(event){
    if (event.toElement !== this) // Did the user click on the row directly?
        return;

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this received a downvote. By adding an onclick to the checkbox and calling stopPropagation(), you're only fixing the problem for a single element. If Edward adds another element to the row, he would have to add another onclick and stopPropagation(). By checking the event target in the onclick of the row, you solve the issue for _all_ child elements at once.